# How to make dashed grid lines intersect making crosshairs in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, line, gridlines

I'm plotting some data and I want to use dashed grid lines.

Any dashed grid line would suffice, but I prefer a "long dash, short dash, long dash" format.

For example, given the following code

```
set grid lc rgb "#000000" lt 1 dt (50, 25, 20, 25)
plot x**2
```

I get this result
[image: plot x**2 naive approach]

But I would rather the grid lines intersection to happen always at the middle of two dashes, like this

[image: grid lines intersecting appropriately]

If I could make horizontal grid lines different to vertical grid lines and I could add some offset to each one, then I'd imagine there's a way to accomplish this. But I can't seem to do that either.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like gnuplot cannot have two different dashstyles for x-grid and y-grid.
One workaround I see currently is to plot two identical plot on top of each other. One with appropriate x-grid lines and the other with appropriate y-grid lines.

If you want a dash pattern with proportions of `(50-25-20-25)`, this correspond to `(25-25-20-25-25-0)` or `(5-5-4-5-5-0)` between two tics.
Furthermore, the dash and gap length numbers, e.g. in `dt (50,25,20,25)`, seem to be in a fixed relation to the graph size. The "empirical" factor is 11 with good approximation (at least for the wxt terminal which I tested under gnuplot 5.2.6).

**Edit:** *actually, the code below gives different results with a `qt` terminal. And it's not just a different factor. It's more complicated and probably difficult to solve without insight into the source code. So, the fact that the following seems to work with `wxt` terminal (maybe even just under Windows?) was probably a lucky strike.*

With this you can create your dash lines automatically resulting in crosshairs at the intersections of the major grid lines.

Assumptions are:

1. your first and last tics are on the borders
2. you know the number of x- and y-intervals

You also need to know the graph size. These values are stored in the variables `GPVAL_TERM...`, but only **after** plotting. That's why you have to `replot` to get the correct values.

This workaround at least should give always crosshairs at the intersection of the major grid lines.

**Edit 2:** *just for "completeness". The factors to get the same (or similar) looking custom dashed pattern on different terminals varies considerably. `wxt` approx. 11, `qt` approx. 5.6, `pngcairo`approx. 0.25. This is not what I would expect. Furthermore, it looks like the factors slightly depend on x and y as well as graph size. In order to get "exact" crosshairs you might have to tweak these numbers a little further.*

Code:

```
### dashed grid lines with crosshairs at intersections
reset session

TERM = "wxt"   # choose terminal

if (TERM eq "wxt") {
    set term wxt size 800,600
    FactorX = 11.    # wxt
    FactorY = 11.    # wxt
}
if (TERM eq "qt") {
    set term qt size 800,600
    FactorX = 5.58  # qt
    FactorY = 5.575   # qt
}
if (TERM eq "pngcairo") {
    set term pngcairo size 800,600
    set output "tbDashTest.png"
    FactorX = 0.249    # pngcairo
    FactorY = 0.251    # pngcairo
}

set multiplot
set ticscale 0,0

Units = 24   # pattern (5,5,4,5,5,0) are 24 units

# set interval and repetition parameters
IntervalsY = 10
RepetitionsY = 1
IntervalsX = 4
RepetitionsX = 3

# initial plot to get graph size
plot x**2
gX = real(GPVAL_TERM_YMAX-GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)/IntervalsY/Units/FactorY/RepetitionsY
gY = real(GPVAL_TERM_XMAX-GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)/IntervalsX/Units/FactorX/RepetitionsX
# first plot with x-grid lines
set grid xtics lt 1 lc rgb "black" dt (gX*5,gX*5,gX*4,gX*5,gX*5,0)
replot
unset grid
# second plot with y-grid lines
set grid ytics lt 1 lc rgb "black" dt (gY*5,gY*5,gY*4,gY*5,gY*5,0)
replot

unset multiplot
set output
### end of code
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This does the job. It's a shame it doesn't work on a qt terminal. So first things first, should we file a bug? Where?
The same code should give the same results independently of the terminal.

Comment: probably, you can tweak it somehow for the qt terminal, but I haven't been successful so far. You're right, I also hoped that this will work on other terminals as well. If you want to file a bug report, you can do this here: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/ maybe we'll get some response from the developers.

Comment: On another note, this doesn't work using ```pngcairo``` or most useful terminals. Specifically, pngcairo doesn't accept the ```dt (length, space, length, space)``` syntax. It may not be a bug, it should though. It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Turns out I'm wrong. It does accept it, but there proportions are far from obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  The closest I can think of is

```
set grid x y mx my
set grid lt -1 lc "black" lw 1 , lt -1 lc bgnd lw 16
set ticscale 1.0, 0.01
set mxtics 4
plot x**2 lw 2
```

But that leaves the vertical grid lines solid.
[image]

Comment: I may be having a problem, because, in my case, running that code the resulting plot has both vertical and horizontal lines solid. Somehow the second command of grid overrides the previous one.

Comment: Try `set grid x y mx my lt -1 lc "black" lw 1 , lt -1 lc bgnd lw 16` to see the effect @Ethan described.

Comment: Oh, that did the trick. Now I get it, it's superimposing white lines over the black ones.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about lt -1 (default border lt) and the colourspec "bgnd".