# Gnuplot: "Complementary" dashed lines

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot "complementary" dashed lines. What I mean is the following: I have three curves that are identical in a certain range of x values but different outside this range. Of course, if I simply plot solid lines on top of each other, I will only see the topmost one (in the range where they are identical). So, I would like to plot them as dashed lines:

```
1st line: dash-space-space-dash-space-space...

2nd line: space-dash-space-space-dash-space...

3rd line: space-space-dash-space-space-dash...
```

Plotting them on top of each other should produce a solid lines with alternating colors (of the three line types).
The most obvious way to achieve this is with the new dashtypes, for example:

```
plot x dt "-  ",x dt " - ",x dt "  -"
```

However, the leading blank is ignored. Also, a definition such as (20,20) does not work because the order of values is always "solid length,emptyspace length". If there were a way to invert this order, the problem could be solved easily.

(By the way, in the case of only two curves, the solution is simple: plot the first as solid and the second as dashed.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
### different shifted dashed lines
reset session

plot x, \
    0 w l lw 3 lc rgb "red" dt (20,40) notitle, \
    0 w l lw 3 lc rgb "web-green" dt (0,20,20,20) notitle, \
    0 w l lw 3 lc rgb "blue" dt (0,40,20,0) notitle

### end of code
```

[image]

**Addition:**

with the following code the result should be the same (or let's say similar) in wxt, qt, postscript, pngcairo (cannot test x11). Well, the dash length is different depending on the terminal (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628295/7295599)

```
### different shifted dashed lines
reset session
# set term wxt
# set term qt
set term pngcairo
set output "DashedLines.png"
# set term postscript color
# set output "DashedLines.eps"

plot x, \
    0 w l lw 3 lc rgb "blue" dt 1 notitle, \
    0 w l lw 3 lc rgb "web-green" dt (40,20) notitle, \
    0 w l lw 3 lc rgb "red" dt (20,40) notitle
set output
### end of code
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks very nice. However, I had the same idea of using a leading "0" in the (...) definition, but my Gnuplot (5.2.6) still does it wrongly.

Terminal x11: All lines start with a dash, i.e., all lines are identical to the red line above.

Terminal qt: The red line is correct again. All others are just solid (no dashes).

Terminal post color: Same as qt.

Comment: oops.. that's not nice from gnuplot if the terminals look different... I used the wxt-terminal but did not test the others. Recently, there was another issue with dashed lines and terminals not looking the same... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625024/how-to-make-dashed-grid-lines-intersect-making-crosshairs-in-gnuplot

Comment: About the addition: Thank you. I did not think of it. Works perfectly with the terminals you mention (cannot test wxt), but not with the terminal x11, which seems to have a bug with "dt (...)".

Comment: about X11 and dashed lines, I found this: https://wiki.octave.org/Enable_%22linestyle%22_functionality_for_Gnuplot%27s_x11_terminal I can't tell whether it is helpful in your case.